# New font for iOS 9 will be applied on Ionic apps?

Tags: ios, cordova, fonts, ionic-framework, ios9

iOS 9 is expected to be released with new font - San Francisco, replacing its tranditional Hevetica fonts. I wonder how Ionic will respond to this kind of change. Here are the things that I am curious to know at this moment.

- Will old Ionic apps automatically use San Francisco font in iOS 9?
- Will new Ionic apps (that are published right after release of iOS 9) use San Francisco font?
- If not, how can I apply this new font in next Ionic apps?

Anyone please help me in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer for iOS web developers would be that it would be included by default at release and could be called via font-family. As of iOS 9 Beta 1, I could not get to the San Francisco font in this way.

font-family: 'San Francisco Display', "Helvetica-Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

-OR-

font-family: 'San Francisco Text', "Helvetica-Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;

depending upon the variant you want.

However, if that proves not to be true at the time of general release, or you want to include it now, you can import the (free) [webfont](http://www.nicholastodor.com/sf/SanFranciscoFont.zip) in your css and use it exactly as stated above.

Hat tip to [Nicholas Todor](http://www.nicholastodor.com/blog/use-apples-new-san-francisco-font-on-your-website) for the information.

Comment: Hi @tabrindle, thanks for your answer.  Does this mean including SF font files in /www folder and pulling it using font-family doesn't work in older versions of iOS?

Comment: Nope. As long as you import it and declare it in font-family it should work on older versions of iOS or anything else you should fancy. Just be careful because it's license specifically states the font is only free for use on Apple devices.